# DisplayNameFor e DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor, html-helpers

Estudando sobre o ASP.NET MVC, me deparei com as seguintes linhas de código:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
```

Estou sem conseguir entender qual a diferença entre usar `DisplayNameFor` e `DisplayFor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title) //mostra Title
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title) //mostra o conteúdo de Title
```

Quase sempre quer usar o [`DisplayFor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Na verdade o [`DisplayNameFor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) mostra o nome da propriedade que pode ser o nome que ela foi declarada ou pode usar um nome diferente anotado com um atributo. Pode ser útil quando você quer mostrar uma descrição do que é o conteúdo. Como a gente não fala inglês e não usamos mnemônicos quase sempre o nome da propriedade não é adequado. Mas se tiver uma anotação do nome então ele pode funcionar como um *label* para o conteúdo. Tem quem prefira ter um *label* separado ou definido na *view* já que pode ter um contexto. Tem quem prefira ter essa vinculação da propriedade com seu nome através de [`Display()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Para anotar um nome pode fazer assim no modelo:

```
public class Livro {
    [Display(Name = "Tíulo do livro")]
    public string Title{ get; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/DisplayFor.cs).

É muito parecido com o [`LabelFor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Answer (score 3):

Segui por [esse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385108/4551469):

```
public class Teste
{
    [Display(Name = "current name")]
    public string Nome { get { return "teste"; } }
}
```

Usando `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)` exibiria o nome da propriedade `Nome` ou (nesse caso) a descrição colocada na propriedade `Display` (*current name*).
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)` exibe o valor da propriedade (*teste*)