# Diferença entre @Html.LabelFor e @Html.DisplayNameFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, razor

Estou iniciando no ASP.NET MVC e fazendo um curso onde o professor utilizou para exibir os dados de uma classe diferentes métodos para exibição de um dado.

Ele utiliza o `@Html.LabelFor` e o `@Html.DisplayNameFor`. Pelo que li em outros fóruns o `@Html.LabelFor` é utilizado mais para criação de formulários, exibe o campo contido em uma classe de um *model*, porém se eu utilizar o `@Html.DisplayNameFor` exibe os mesmos dados.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `DisplayNameFor()` gera um texto puro com o título daquele elemento, já o `LabelFor` gera uma *tag* `label` do HTML com o texto do título, assim:

```
<label for="Campo">Título</label>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Label.cshtml).

O que aparecerá na página é o mesmo, mas a semântica dentro da página é muito diferente. O segundo identifica o que é aquilo na página, o primeiro só é um texto sem significado para a página/aplicação.

Por isso que eu falo que tem que aprender como é e não como aparece. É a mesma confusão que as pessoas fazem com "funcionar" e "estar certo", tem um monte de coisa que está errada e funciona, e a pessoas que aprende errado não consegue identificar que está errado, porque parece certo. Mas só parece.

[image: Funcionar é diferente de estar certo]

Esta é a maior dica que pode receber em tudo. Quando a pessoa não busca a informação correta, ao contrário do AP está fazendo o certo e buscando, vive em eterno [efeito Dunning Krueger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Ambos pegam o título determinado por [`[DisplayName("")]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) no modelo, ou o nome do campo se não tiver a anotação especificada.

[Veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227462/101).

Comment: Eu adicionaria que ambos vão utilizar a data annotaion `[DisplayName("")]` do atributo e caso não exista, ele utiliza o próprio nome.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo feito! Obrigado.